# Помогите создать рабочую конфигурация для ведения логов

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

Помогите создать рабочую конфигурация для ведения логов. Вот мой pom.xml:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.valid.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j.configuration>log4j2.xml</log4j.configuration>           
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>         
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Так все работает, только slf4j использует logback, как сделать чтобы он использовал log4j?
Если я удаляю секцию c logback, то логи просто перестают выводиться, а в начале выскакивает сообщение:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (ru.valid.test).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Вот файл с минимальными настройками log4j2.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="ru.valid.test.Test" level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

вот пример конфига для log4j:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, file, stdout
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.file.File=Logsllog.txt
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=6
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
log4j.logger.org.springframework=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.valid.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j.configuration>log4j2.xml</log4j.configuration>           
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

вот код записи логов:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WindowFunction.class);
logger.debug("test");
```

Comment: Никаких дополнительных slf4j не надо. Достаточно только log4j-slf4j-impl

Comment: оставил один только log4j-slf4j-impl, в итоге логи совсем не пишутся, конфиг тут не причем, т.к. он все равно должен их писать

Comment: Скопировал ваш код, убрал лишние зависимости и все заработало

Comment: Отправьте код, как в лог пишете

Comment: действительно заработало, только он пишет одни ERROR, поэтому сразу не заметил. Нужен конфиг, где он у вас лежит? Я выложил пример своего конфига для log4j. И я не пойму, ведь везде пишут, что slf4j работает через log4j, т.е. надо и его указывать

Comment: log4j-slf4j-impl уже включает slf4j-api. slf4j - обертка, log4j - реализация

Comment: В pom.xml надо либо убрать <targetPath/>, чтобы log4j2.xml попал в корень. Либо   указать путь до log4j2.xml [тут описание](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: тыкните носом где. Я нашел только, что он должен лежать в the classpath

Comment: В classpath. У вас получается он лежит в classpath/resources. Чтобы указать другой путь можно запустить приложение с указанием пути "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///path_to_file"

Comment: Если используете Spring Boot, то можно добавить свойство в application.properties: logging.config: path_to_file